# Why path with "-" is not working in vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I am trying to define path as

```js
{
      path: '/:not-found(.*)',
      name:'Not-Found',
      component : NotFound
}
```

which is not working in vue 3, bit when I am trying to define same path as

```js
{
      path: '/:notFound(.*)',
      name:'Not-Found',
      component : NotFound
}
```

it is working fine. Why so?

Why such behavior from vue 3? I am using "vue-router": "^4.2.5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue-router internally converts all paths to a regex expression, and the hyphen is simply not considered part of a dynamic path segment.  When you use the hyphen, you break the regex.  You can consider using camel case for dynamic path segments as a requirement.

See the resultant regex using vue-router's [path ranking tool](https://paths.esm.dev/?p=AAMeJbiAwQ4F7LTANQNdgROgUACADgJUBVAkATgAYAiAOcWmAAA.#)

`/:not-found(.*)` becomes `/^\/([^/]+?)-found\(\.\*\)\/?$/i`

`/:notfound(.*)` becomes `/^\/([^/]+?)\/?$/i`

Comment: But I was able to use
{
  path: "user-detail",
  component: UserDetails
}
So how come this was working and not the other one?

Comment: it's only for dynamic paths that the hyphen breaks the regex